# Unit Tests on V3 fails with Exception in thread "FiberTimedScheduler-Same thread scheduler" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: corda

I ran the gradlew with

```
./gradlew -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx2048m" test
```

and also make the following entry in the build.gradle

```
test {
    jvmArgs('-XX:+UseG1GC', '-Xmx2048m')
    maxHeapSize = "2048m"
}
```

and I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "FiberTimedScheduler-Same thread scheduler" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.FiberTimedScheduler.findProblemFibers(FiberTimedScheduler.java:402)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.FiberTimedScheduler.work(FiberTimedScheduler.java:140)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.FiberTimedScheduler.access$000(FiberTimedScheduler.java:45)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.FiberTimedScheduler$1.run(FiberTimedScheduler.java:81)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "FiberTimedScheduler-Same thread scheduler" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "FiberTimedScheduler-Same thread scheduler" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "FiberTimedScheduler-Same thread scheduler" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Answer (score 0):

This might resolve the issue. Try Configuring JVM properties as per the instructions [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have no issues running from IntelliJ. I need to get this running from gradle for CI builds